# Not able to update choiceField using jquery in django forms

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am using django Modelform to create form. I want to update my choicefied according to previous choice selected. I am using jquery but below code is not working.
Here is my code:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from feedback_form.models import course, batch

class loginForm(forms.Form):
    course_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=course.objects.values_list('course_name', flat = True))
    batch = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=batch.objects.none())

class Meta:
    model = batch
    fields = ('course_name', 'batch')
```

models.py

```
class course(models.Model):
    course_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 2)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    stream = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    number_of_sem = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.course_id

    class batch(models.Model):
        batch_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 20)
        course_id = models.ForeignKey(course)
        session = models.IntegerField("Year of the batch", max_length = 10)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.batch_id
```

loginForm.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    {% csrf_token%}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('select#id_course_name').change(function(){
       c_name = $(this).val();
       request_url = '/get_batch/' + c_name + '/';
       $.ajax({
         url: request_url,
         success: function(data){
            $.each(data[0], function(key, value){
                $('select#id_batch').append('<option value="' + this.key + '">' + this.value +'</option>');
            });  
        }
        return false;
    })
    })
    }); 
 </script>
 </body>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import json
import feedback_form.models

def get_batch(request, c_id):
current_course = feedback_form.models.course.objects.get(course_name=c_id)
batches = feedback_form.models.batch.objects.all().filter(batch_id=current_course)
batch_dict = {}
for batch in batches:
    batch_dict[batch.id] = batch.batch_id
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(batch_dict), mimetype="application/json")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^get_batch/(?P<c_name>[-\w]+)/$', views.get_batch, name = 'get_batch'),
```

please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "my code is not working"?

Comment: quick looks: `$('select#id_course_name').change(function(){` should be `$('#id_course_name').change(function(){`

Comment: describe more what is/isn't happening.  i.e. when you make a change to id_course_name selection, what happens?

Comment: on removing `mimetype = "application/json"` it is showing updated list on url "/get_batch/MCA/" but not on my actual form url i.e "/login". It is showing empty choiceField for batch.

Comment: @ warath-coder: on selecting id_course_name, no choices are shown in batch field. plz help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved. Since here the data received in ajax function for id_batch (or data) is of string type, thatswhy it is not showing any value in choiceField. By adding:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

after

```
success: function(data){
```

and removing this pointer form the key and value variable means

```
$('#id_batch').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +'</option>');
```

solved my problem. For detailed information, check out [here](https://jee-appy.blogspot.in/2015/11/how-to-apply-ajax-in-django-forms.html).
Thanks